# Django bicrypt password different from ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, django

I have ruby app with mysql database which has password stored.I don't know ruby but from internet what i found is that ruby stores password in bicrypt format.
I created one user with password : Password123.
What i printed in console was its encrypted password.

Tasks:
Now i am creating a django app which needs to be connected to same database.I need to verify password from same database.That is i used bicrypt algorithm in django dummy app and created user with same password : Password123.

But encrypted text from ruby app and django app are different.It needs to be same for verification from django app.

How to do this? Why bicrypt output of both language different.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you mean bcrypt. I don't know what bicrypt is. The 'encrypted' password is probably salted to protect against rainbow attacks, which is why they have different 'encrypted' values.

Why do you need the 'encrypted' password to be the same on both systems? Does using 'Password123' on either system not work?

Comment: because they both have same database and matching of stored password is done from that database.